# Canvas.toDataURL() not showing background image of canvas

Tags: html, d3.js, svg, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have added background image to canvas using css.

But when converting it into png using canvas.toDataURL() , its not showing background image.

It seems like its not parsing css background image.

```
var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        d3.select('canvas')
          .attr('style', 'background-image:url("chart.png");background-position:50%;background-repeat:no-repeat');

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
        var img = new Image();
        //var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
        var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml"});
        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);


        var png = '';



        img.onload = function() {


           ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
           document.querySelector('#chart').innerHTML = '<img src="'+png+'"/>';
            DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
            img.src = "";
        };
        img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";


        img.src = url;
```

Comment: That is because the background is not part of the canvas. You need to render that in the canvas in order to save it.

Comment: Can you please tell how to render it ?

Comment: Even if i am adding background image in svg , its not be able to convert to canvas on safari browser.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/q7Z9k/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado this background works . But i need to render svg on top of that background.

Please suggest.

Comment: You need to render an SVG on top of an HTML5-Canvas that has a PNG as a background? Wow, this is out of my expertise... let's wait to see if someone else helps you (also, I'll rollback the edition in your question, I had removed the SVG tag).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado , Actually while converting from svg to canvas using canvas.todataurl() , svg background is not being shown on safari . 

Thats why i planned to add the same background image on canvas on top of canvas svg image.

Comment: I'm a little bit lost here: is the background a png or a svg?

Comment: Just before you export with `toDataURL`, set `globalCompositeOperation='destination-over'` and then `drawImage` the background image onto the canvas. That background image will be added *behind the existing drawings* and will then appear on your exported data url.

Comment: png
My need is  : 
1. Draw svg on canvas using svg bolb as url (check my code)

2. Draw background of that canvas .

Comment: @markE let me try it and i will let you know.

Comment: Or just drawImage your background just before you draw your svg.. The problem with your svg's background disappearing is that `<img>` can't load external resources from its loaded media. So an other - not recommended in your case - solution, would have been to first convert your background image to a dataURI, set the svg style inline, and then you should have been able to export it.

Comment: @Kaiido Can you please send me one jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This solution is working 

var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
        var img = new Image();
        //var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
        var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml"});
        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

        var png = '';
        var emailConfirmationMessage = '';
        var img1 = new Image();

        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img1, 136, 136);
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            sendEmail(canvas,DOMURL);

        };

         img1.onload = function(){
           img.src = url;
         };
        img1.src = 'chart1.png';
```

Comment: Here if we will assign url to  svg image when background image is loading , then its working on all browsers

Comment: I will be posting one jsfiddle soon

Comment: jsfiddle will help to understand it properly thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, `background-image` is not part of the canvas context and thus, can't be exported by any canvas' export methods.

If you want to get this image drawn on the canvas, simply draw it before you draw the other image.* The main difficulty being to reproduce the different option CSS background has. But in your case, it's quite simple.

```js
var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;

var svg = new Blob([svgString], {
  type: "image/svg+xml"
});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
var png = '';

var toLoad = 2;
var loaded = 0;
var background = new Image();
var svgImg = new Image();

// attach the event to both images
background.onload = svgImg.onload = function(){
 // only when both has loaded
 if(++loaded === toLoad){
  
  // set the canvas size to the svg image's one
  canvas.width = svgImg.width;
  canvas.height = svgImg.height;
  
  // draw the background image first
  ctx.drawImage(background, (canvas.width/2)-(background.width/2), (canvas.height/2)-(background.height/2));
 // then the svg image
  ctx.drawImage(svgImg, 0, 0);
  png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.querySelector('#chart').innerHTML = '<img src="' + png + '"/>';
  // you want to revoke the svgImg ObjectURL, not the canvas dataURI
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(svgImg.src);
 
 }
}
svgImg.src = url;
// set it only if you're doing a cross origin request
// Object URL are not
background.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
background.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png'
```

```css
svg{border: 1px solid red;}
canvas{border: 1px solid blue;}
img{border: 1px solid green;}
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="55" height="55" fill-opacity=".5"/>
</svg>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<p id="chart"></p>
```

*As said by markE, if you can't draw the background **before**, you can also set the `globalCompositeOperation` of your context to `destination-over` in order to draw **behind** the actual content.

---

Now, this wasn't clearly part of your question, but if you tried to set the `background-image` to your svg node, you should have been able to draw it on your canvas image, as part of the svg.

But since HTMLImage (`<img>`) element can't load any external resources form its loaded media, you would have to first convert the image to a dataURI version, and append the styles either as the svg's `style` attribute,  either in a `<style>` element appended inside the svg element.

Here is a ugly example that will convert an svg element with a CSS defined background-image, and draw it on the canvas.
<sub>*Don't use it, this just here for the demo but is likely to break. Also, this has only been quickly tested against FF, Chrome and Safari.*</sub>

```js
function convertSVGWithBG(svg, callback) {

  // this function is not be bullet proof, better if you know the urls in advance

  // in case of multi-images
  var imgsToLoad = getComputedStyle(svg).backgroundImage.split(',');

  appendDocumentStylesTo(svg);

  var toLoad = imgsToLoad.length,
    loaded = 0,
    // we need to keep it sorted
    rules = [],
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  imgsToLoad.forEach(function(s, i) {

    var bgURL = parseURL(s),
      bgImg = new Image();
    bgImg.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

    var errored = false;

    bgImg.onload = function() {
      canvas.width = this.width;
      canvas.height = this.height;
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      rules[i] = canvas.toDataURL();
      if (++loaded === toLoad) {
        onend();
      }
      bgImg.onerror = function() {

        if (!errored) {
          errored = true;
          this.crossOrigin = null;
          this.removeAttribute('crossorigin');
          this.src = this.src;
        } else {
          console.warn('failed to load img at src ', this.src);
          if (--toLoad === loaded) {
            onend();
          }
        }
      };
    };

    bgImg.src = bgURL;

    function onend() {
      var toLoad = rules.filter(function(r) {
          return r;
        }).length,
        loaded = 0;
      // wait for the dataURI version has loaded too
      rules.forEach(function(url) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
          if (++loaded === toLoad) {

            callback(svg);

          }
        };
        img.src = url
      });
      // it has to be inline style, or appended in a <style> element directly in our svg element
      var fullRule = 'url(' + rules.join('), url(') + ')';
      svg.style.backgroundImage = fullRule;
    }

  });

  function parseURL(str) {
    // this is ugly and there should be a better way to do so (maybe regex)
    var url = str.split('"')[1];
    if (!url) {
      url = str.split("'")[1];
    }
    if (!url) {
      url = str.split('(')[1].split(')')[0];
    }
    return url;
  }
}

function svgToCanvas(svg) {

  var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;

  var svg = new Blob([svgString], {
    type: "image/svg+xml"
  });
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

  var svgImg = new Image();
  svgImg.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = svgImg.width;
    canvas.height = svgImg.height;
    ctx.drawImage(svgImg, 0, 0);
    png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.querySelector('#chart').innerHTML = '<img src="' + png + '"/>';
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(svgImg.src);
  }
  svgImg.src = url;

}

var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
convertSVGWithBG(svg, svgToCanvas);

// this is completely unstable and should never be used...
function appendDocumentStylesTo(element) {

  var docStyleSheets = document.styleSheets;
  var i = 0,
    j, rules, r, key;
  for (i; i < docStyleSheets.length; i++) {
    rules = docStyleSheets[i].cssRules;
    for (j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
      r = rules[j];
      if (element.matches(r.selectorText)) {

        if (r.style) {
          for (k = 0; k < r.style.length; k++) {
            key = r.style[k];
            // ugly hack for Safari
            if (key.indexOf('repeat') > -1) {
              key = 'background-repeat';
            }
            element.style[key] = r.style[key];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
svg {
  background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rumlhyme6s5f8pt/ABC.png), url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png);
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="55" height="55" fill-opacity=".5" />
</svg>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<p id="chart"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Have you checked on safari ?
On safari , background image of svg is not showing after converting to canvas

Comment: @LakinMohapatra, actually that was a problem with crossOrigin attribute, my bad. Now it should work on Safari too. And I added a waiting function to make sure even dataURIs version has loaded. But once again, **don't use the second snippet** In your case, the first one is largely enough and way more stable !

Comment: Let me check and i will let you know

Comment: First snippet is also not working.

BDW i made it to work.

Please look into my answer

Comment: can you please tell canvas.toDataURL() is showing security error on IE browser? How to overcome it ? Please suggest

Comment: You can't. IE before Edge tainted the canvas when any svg image has been drawn on it for security reasons. The only way is to convert you svg to canvas drawing commands (`ctx.lineTo` etc.) While I don't find it perfect, canvg library does this.

Comment: So should i use canvg library for IE ?

Comment: Yes if you need to export the svg to bitmap. through js. Otherwise, IE user can right click the svg and convert it directly to png. Also, my first snippet does work on my Safari, and should work on any UA.

Comment: Actually i need to send it via email. So i need to convert my svg to png anyway on all browsers because svg is not supported in ost of the email clients. 
What's your safari version ?
Have you tried it by opening it in private window?